# Slow Parallel programming - MPI, VB.NET and FORTRAN

Tags: vb.net, performance, fortran, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm working on parallelizing a software which simulates transport and flow process in the unsaturated soil zone. The software consists of a VB.NET user interface, and a FORTRAN DLL kernel to do the calculations.
I parallelized the software by using the package MPI.NET in the VB.NET part. When the program is started with a number of processes, all of them but the master process go into a wait function, while the master process takes care of the interaction of the software with the user. When all the data required for the simulation is entered, the master process enters the FORTRAN DLL, and calls the other processes. These jump to the starting point of the function in the DLL, and together all the processes solve a linear system of equations for about 10-20 times (the original partial differential equation is nonlinear, therefore these iterations in order to gain accuracy in the solution). When the solution is computed, all the processes go back to VB.NET, This is done for all the timesteps of the simulation. When all steps are computed, the master process continues with the user interaction, while the other processes go back 
into the wait function, until they are called again by the master process.
The thing is that this program runs much slower than the original, sequential version of it. Now there might be a number of reasons for this. I used the PETSc library in the FORTRAN DLL to solve the system of equations, and I think I have configured it quite well. My question is if at some point in the architecture I described there could be a point or two which could cause a significant slowdown if not handled correctly. I'm not sure f.e. if the subsequent calls of DLL function can cost a lot of time.
My system is a Intel Xeon 3470 processor with 8GB RAM. The systems I tried to solve had up to 120.000 unknowns, which I know is at the very lower bound of what should be calculated in parallel, but at least with the 120.000 matrix I would have expected a better performance than I did measure.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

I would say that 120,000 degrees of freedom and 10-20 iterations is not that large a problem.  Million degree of freedom problems were done when I did finite element analysis for a living, and that was 16 years ago.

Is it possible to solve it using an in-memory solver, without parallelization, with 8GB of RAM?  That would certainly be your benchmark.  Is that what you're comparing your parallel results to?

Are the parallel processes running on different processors or different machines?  Parallelization doesn't buy you anything if everything is done on a single processor.  You have to context switch and time slice processes, and there's overhead associated with MPI to communicate between processes.  I would expect a parallel solution on a single processor to run more slowly than a single thread, in-memory solution.

If you have multiple processes, then I'd say it's a matter of tuning.  I'd plot performance versus number of parallel processes.  If there's a speedup, you should find that it improves with more processes until you reach a saturation point, beyond which the overhead is greater than the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple cores, when you run your program sequentially can you see that only one or a few processor are utilized? 
If the load in the sequential case is high and evenly distributed over all cores then IMHO there is no need to parallelize your program.

Answer (score 0):

My system has a Xeon 3470, which is a quadcore processor. So the computations are all done on these 4 on 1 machine. I don't run the program with more than 4 processes of course.The old solver that the software had was sequential of course, and that still runs faster than the parallel version. When I plot number of processes against runtime, I see that runtime even increases a little bit with smaller models - but that is to be expected because of the communication overhead.

In both the sequential and the parallel case all 4 processors are utilized, and the load balance between them is acceptable.

Like I said, I know that the models I've tested so far are not ideal to talk about parallel performance. I was just wondering if besides the communication overhead due to MPI there could still be another point that could lead to the slowdown of the program.

Comment: This should not be a separate answer. If you want to give extra info, you can edit your original question; if you want to reply to a specific answer, you can place a comment below it.

Comment: @eriktous: I guess Martin posted this as an answer because he accidentally created and logged in under another account. @Martin: You can [ask the moderators to merge your accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801), so you can better keep track of your posts and also comment on them.